# Convex hull around D3 Force network graphic

Tags: d3.js, networking, graph, convex-hull

I'm trying to add a hull around the D3 network graph that I've build.
My network is based on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/bpKG4/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=bpKG4) (can't share mine because of sensitive data) and basically the end product should be a network with a shade around. I read a lot online and found that a convex hull might be a solution. After trying to implement my data in tutorials like this one http://bl.ocks.org/donaldh/2920551, I must come to the conclusion that my basic D3 knowledge won't be enough to solve this.

Thank you all in advance!

```
//Constants for the SVG
var width = 500,
height = 500;

//Set up the colour scale
var color = d3.scale.category20();

//Set up the force layout
var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-120)
.linkDistance(30)
.size([width, height]);

//Append a SVG to the body of the html page. Assign this SVG as an object to         svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

//Read the data from the mis element 
var mis = document.getElementById('mis').innerHTML;
graph = JSON.parse(mis);

//Creates the graph data structure out of the json data
force.nodes(graph.nodes)
.links(graph.links)
.start();

//Create all the line svgs but without locations yet
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
.data(graph.links)
.enter().append("line")
.attr("class", "link")
.style("stroke-width", function (d) {
return Math.sqrt(d.value);
});

//Do the same with the circles for the nodes - no 
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("r", 8)
.style("fill", function (d) {
return color(d.group);
})
.call(force.drag);


//Now we are giving the SVGs co-ordinates - the force layout is generating the         co-ordinates which this code is using to update the attributes of the SVG elements
force.on("tick", function () {
link.attr("x1", function (d) {
    return d.source.x;
})
    .attr("y1", function (d) {
    return d.source.y;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By following the basic [example here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341699), you should be able to incorporate the minimum convex hull fairly easily. In the basic example, the hull is created here:

```
var hull = svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "hull");
```

And updated here:

```
hull.datum(d3.geom.hull(vertices)).attr("d", function(d) { return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; });
```

However, I was unable to get the x and y accessors to access `d.x` and `d.y`; in the example block above the hull takes an array of points ([documentation here](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Hull-Geom.md), [possible solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092006/d3-geom-hull-with-custom-accessors)). So I've created an example that creates an intermediate variable that contains all the points:

```
node.data().forEach(function(d,i) {
    vertices[i] = [d.x,d.y]; 
})
```

And then updates as in the example above:

```
hull.datum(d3.geom.hull(vertices)).attr("d", function(d) {  return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"; });
```

Here's a [block](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/a4cb68e03503b1b1ae47729cd4746848) showing it in action based on the example fiddle.

D3v4 doesn't offer much streamlining - there are no accessor functions for d3.polygonHull in v4; I've created a [block here](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/1ff1d11c396a887640a822f03cfa0924) for v4.

Comment: You are a life saver Andrew! This works perfectly. 
Thank you so much for your time!