# How to visualize groups of nodes in a d3 force-directed graph layout

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm looking for a way to plug in groups to my force-directed graph visualization. I've found three related examples so far:

- [Cola.js](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/smallworldwithgroups.html) which would require adding another library and possibly retro-fitting my code to fit this different library.
- [This block](http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3071239), which is pretty hard to untangle.
- [This slide](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20110921/#14) from mbostock's slide deck, which isn't what I want but on the right path...

What I'd like most is a simple way of adding something very close to the structure from the first link, but without too much overhead.

Right now I have a pretty standard setup:

```
var link = g.selectAll(".link")
            .data(graph.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style(...

var node = g.selectAll(".node")
            .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
```

I was hoping to just grab the d3 code out of cola.js and mess with it, but that library seems fairly complicated so it wouldn't be too easy. I'm hoping it isn't too hard to get something kind of like this in straight d3:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for non-complex shapes (bounding box or convex hull), you can probably do that relatively easily by calculating the shape for each group - but overlaps are likely. There are some convex hull examples out there for force layouts:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/45912361/7106086

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I'm looking for something which preferably does not overlap. Do you think there's a block out there for such a thing?

Comment: I can't say I've seen one - detection of overlap would require quite a bit of added complexity and then you would need some method of pushing the force layout to separate nodes when overlaps are detected. These would require the force to be cooled down a bit - no sense in trying to separate nodes when the force is first initialized.

Comment: @AndrewReid I imagine it's *possible* to get this to work in d3, since it's been done at least once. I've started a bounty in case anyone thinks they can figure it out!

Comment: I can't see it being impossible, though it could be fairly involved depending on the desired result. I hope that my answer is useful if it is a slightly different outcome than intended. Though, if willing to skew the placement of the nodes to favor the groups more than the links, you could probably use a bounding box rather than a voronoi.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*I'm following the title "visualize groups of nodes" more than the suggested picture, but I think it wouldn't be that hard to tweak my answer to show bounding boxes as in the image*

There's probably a few d3 only solutions, all of them almost certainly require tweaking the node positions manually to keep nodes grouped properly.  The end result won't strictly be typical of a force-layout because links and node positions must be manipulated to show grouping in addition to connectivity - consquently, the end result will be a compromise between each force - node charge, length strength and length, and group.

The easiest way to accomplish your goal may be to:

1. Weaken link strength when links link different groups
2. On each tick, calculate each group's centroid
3. Adjust each node's position to move it closer to the group's centroid
4. Use a voronoi diagram to show the groupings

For my example here, I'll use Mike's canonical [force layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).

#### Weaken links when links link different groups

Using the linked example, we can dampen the link strength when link target and link source have different groups. The specified strength will likely need to be altered depending on the nature of the force layout - more inter-connected groups will likely need to have weaker intergroup link strength.

To change the link strength depending on if we have an intergroup link or not, we might use:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).strength(function(link) {   
      if (link.source.group == link.source.target) {
        return 1; // stronger link for links within a group
      }
      else {
        return 0.1; // weaker links for links across groups
      }   
      }) )
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-20))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

#### On Each Tick, Calculate Group Centroids

We want to force group nodes together, to do so we need to know the centroid of the group. The data structure of `simulation.nodes()` isn't the most amenable to calculating centroids, so we need to do a bit of work:

```
var nodes = this.nodes();
var coords ={};
var groups = [];

// sort the nodes into groups:  
node.each(function(d) {
    if (groups.indexOf(d.group) == -1 ) {
        groups.push(d.group);
        coords[d.group] = [];
    }
    coords[d.group].push({x:d.x,y:d.y});    
})

// get the centroid of each group:
var centroids = {};

for (var group in coords) {
    var groupNodes = coords[group];
    var n = groupNodes.length;
    var cx = 0;
    var tx = 0;
    var cy = 0;
    var ty = 0;

    groupNodes.forEach(function(d) {
        tx += d.x;
        ty += d.y;
    })

    cx = tx/n;
    cy = ty/n;

    centroids[group] = {x: cx, y: cy}   
}
```

#### Adjust each node's position to move it closer to its group's centroid:

We don't need to adjust every node - just those that are straying fairly far from their centroids. For those that are sufficiently far we can nudge them closer using a weighted average of the centroid and the node's current position.

I modify the minimum distance used to determine if a node should be adjusted as the visualization cools. For the majority of the time when the visualization is active, when alpha is high, the priority is grouping, so most nodes will be forced towards the grouping centroid. As alpha drops towards zero, nodes should be grouped already, and the need to coerce their position is less important:

```
// don't modify points close the the group centroid:
var minDistance = 10;

// modify the min distance as the force cools:
if (alpha < 0.1) {
    minDistance = 10 + (1000 * (0.1-alpha))
}

// adjust each point if needed towards group centroid:
node.each(function(d) {
    var cx = centroids[d.group].x;
    var cy = centroids[d.group].y;
    var x = d.x;
    var y = d.y;
    var dx = cx - x;
    var dy = cy - y;

    var r = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)

    if (r>minDistance) {
        d.x = x * 0.9 + cx * 0.1;
        d.y = y * 0.9 + cy * 0.1;
    }
})
```

#### Use a Voronoi Diagram

This allows the easiest grouping of nodes - it ensures that there is no overlap between group shells. I haven't built in any verification to ensure that a node or set of node's aren't isolated from the rest of their group - depending on the visualization's complexity you might need this.

*My initial thought was using a hidden canvas to calculate if shells overlapped, but with a Voronoi you could probably calculate if each group is consolidated using neighboring cells. In the event of non-consolidated groups you could use a stronger coercion on stray nodes*.

To apply the voronoi is fairly straightforward:

```
  // append voronoi  
  var cells = svg.selectAll()
  .data(simulation.nodes())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("fill",function(d) { return color(d.group); })
  .attr("class",function(d) { return d.group })

  var cell = cells.append("path") 
    .data(voronoi.polygons(simulation.nodes()))
```

And update on each tick:

```
// update voronoi:
cell = cell.data(voronoi.polygons(simulation.nodes())).attr("d", renderCell);
```

#### Results

Altogether, this looks like this during the grouping phase:

[image]

And as the visualization finally stops:

[image]

If the first image is preferable, then remove the part the changes the `minDistance` as alpha cools down.

Here's [a block](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/e689546e3449fd9f1fba1d19c30d6f6d) using the above method.

#### Further Modification

Rather than using the centroid of each group's nodes, we could use another force diagram to position the ideal centroid of each group. This force diagram would have a node for each group, the strength of links between each group would correspond to te number of links between the nodes of the groups. Using this force diagram, we could coerce the original nodes towards our idealized centroids - the nodes of the second force layout.

This approach may have advantages in certain situations, such as by separating groups by greater amounts. This approach might give you something like:

[image]

I've included an example here, but hope that the code is commented sufficiently to understand without a breakdown like the above code.

Block of [second example](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/99e4d6ade2a656b6952dfed901f41720).

The voronoi is easy, but not always the most aesthetic, you could use a clip path to keep clip the polygons to some sort of oval, or use a gradient overlay to fade the polygons out as they reach the edges. One option that is likely possible depending on graph complexity is using a minimum convex polygon instead, though this won't work well with groups with less than three nodes. Bounding box's probably won't work in most instances, unless you really keep the coercion factor high (eg: keep `minDistance` very low the entire time). The trade off will always be what do you want to show more: connections or grouping.

Comment: By the way, the second block is secret -- not sure that's intentional

Comment: Oh, and one more question: What if each of the groups had a name, which you'd like to display floating somewhere in the voronoi?

Comment: With one centroid per group, you should be able to take the centroids, update text positions based on the centroids, and as they have an identifier (which groups the nodes), you should be able to either display the identifier, or look up a name with the identifier. Here's a quick [demo](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/0ce2069593df3cd43a9e5abea67af196) (secret again, if I have time I'll do a write up and make them more public). Also, you should be able to get the path centroid of the voronoi, but this placement might be a bit odd: centroids of nodes and centroids of voronoi cells won't overlap.

Comment: What do you think causes the nodes to "vibrate" as the simulation is coalescing in the second example? Also, why do you do `var cells = g.selectAll()` What are you selecting there?

Comment: g.selectAll() is the same as g.selectAll(null) - it gives me an empty selection in which everything in .data() will be entered. I was a little puzzled about the vibration too, I'm not too sure, it could just be the hard boundary between pulling points to the centroid or leaving them alone - a gradient might be better for that. Alternatively, you could run the simulation and draw it after.

Comment: I challenge you to try to get the non-overlapping bounding box approach to work (as in the cola example image in the question). My graphs are a little less well behaved than the canonical example, and so the voronoi isn't as pretty because it has many non-contiguous regions (though I suppose I could make it less than 0.1). I think the bounding box approach might be more elegant though. Want to give it a try?