# d3 force directed graphs have grouped items overlap each other

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

I have this plunker (https://next.plnkr.co/edit/17t5ujwC71IK3PCi) which shows d3 graph of nodes grouped together based on group ID. Graph appears fine but I need to make sure that the groups never overlap each other (as shown below where orange, blue and lightblue are different groups but they are appearing on top of each other).

Dragging them causes the graph to endlessly move (which is another issue) and doesn't always fix the overlapping issue. I saw another example (http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3071239) which is a bit better but its made with d3.v2. It has quite some good space between each group which makes it easier to analyze.

I thought setting `charge` to a negative value will do the magic but setting it like `.force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-30))` didn't help at all.

**Problem:**

Now, trying to make the groups distant apart by coding something like following from the d3.v2 example I mentioned above but having hard time cooking something similar for my d3.v4. Any good suggestions on how to dynamically keep all groups away from each other?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following https://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/302096884d5fbc1817062492605b50dd to use forceX and forceY for positioning same group nodes together - away from other groups. Problem with it is that group positions are hardcoded as following:

```
this.grpPositions = {
  '1': {x: 100, y: 100},
  '2': {x: 900, y: 200},
  '3': {x: 700, y: 400},
  '4': {x: 200, y: 400},
  '5': {x: 500, y: 400},
  '6': {x: 600, y: 500}
};
```

I will have to come up with some good algorithm to dynamically generate far apart group x, y co-ordinates based on total number of groups and available width and height of given SVG.

If you have a better way of doing it via d3, please feel free to post your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Two possible options to build off of this could be using a group centroid based on the position of each node in that group in a regular force layout or using a second force layout to position the group centroids (this requires counting or measuring the combined links between nodes of different groups). Tinkering with the forces and attraction to the group centroid would likely minimize the chances of any overlap. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001854/7106086) mostly covers the first, but provides an example of the second option (just ignore the parts about a voronoi).

Comment: Thanks @andrewreid. That's a very detailed reply. I will try to incorporate it in my graph.