# D3 repulsive forces on certain nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make a force directed layout in 3D.

The graph is connected, so each node has at least one edge to another node.

In particular I split my graph into different sets.
Let A and B be disjoint sets, then i want to add repulsive forces between each of these nodes.

So each node in A should have a repulsive force against each node in B.

Is there a way to apply these forces? I only found ways to either directly
determine the x and y position of nodes or applying forces through links, but in this case
maybe some nodes in A and B are not connected through a edge but still should repusle each other.

Thank you in advance.

As pseudo code for the solution i imagined something like this:

```
lrepulsion = list of links
for a in componentA
    for b in componentB
        lrepulsion.add(source: a, target: b);

simulation.force("repulsion", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
                return d.id;
}));

simulation.force("repulsion").distance(function(d) { return -d.value; });
simulation.force("repulsion").links(lrepulsion);
simulation.alpha(1).restart();
```

a and b contain information about the nodes of the graph that are used to draw the graph (like id, etc.).

I have the following code (but the forces are still attracting instead of pushing each other away):

```
simulation
    .force("repulsion", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
        return d.id;
    }));
simulation.force("repulsion").distance(function(d) {
    return -d.value;
});

simulation.force("repulsion").strength(0.1);
let listofrepulsions = [];
for(let k = 0; k < bars.length; k++)
{
    if(!bars[k].selected)
    {
        continue;
    }
    let index = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < bars[k].componentA.length; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < bars[k].componentB.length; j++) {
            let link = {};
            link.target = bars[k].componentB[j];
            link.source = bars[k].componentA[i];
            link.id = index;
            link.value = 2;
            index = index + 1;
            listofrepulsions.push(link);
        }
    }
}

console.log(listofrepulsions);

simulation.force("repulsion")
    .links(listofrepulsions);
simulation.alpha(1).restart();
```

`bars` contains all pairs of clusters that should repel each other.

Preferable I would like to add repulsion to two nodes without adding a link between them but this repulsion should also not influence other nodes.

Comment: To clarify, are you are looking for a layout where all the a's cluster together and all the b's cluster together, regardless of links?

Comment: In general the graph is connected (so only one connected component). It should have a weak force centering and a weak force which makes all nodes repulse each other.
Then by selecting 2 disjoint clusters, i want the nodes in these clusters to repulse each other (adding force to all nodes). Does this answer the question?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001854/7106086) might be useful - it also uses a voronoi background, but without that, it sounds like what you're after.

Comment: Thank you, but it can also occur that a and b (from cluster A and B) are not connected, is there a way to directly apply a force to these two nodes?

Comment: Could you share a code sample on which we could base a proposed solution?

Comment: I added some code of how i think a solution can work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

```
// data.nodes contains all nodes
for(let i = 0; i < data.nodes.length - 1; i++){
    for(let j = i + 1; j < data.nodes.length; j++){
        simulation.force(data.nodes[i].id.concat(data.nodes[j].id), isolate(d3.forceManyBodyReuse().strength(-30), data.nodes[i], data.nodes[j]));
    }
}

function isolate(force, nodeA, nodeB) {
    let initialize = force.initialize;
    force.initialize = function() { initialize.call(force, [nodeA, nodeB]); };
    return force;
}
```

For each pair of nodes i can create their own repulsion force which can later be manipulated, as I can access the force by using the id combination as a name.