# ReactJS TSX clustered D3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js, tsx

How can I convert this to ractjs TSX code. I can't find schemeCategory20 / voronoi kind of things when I convert

Reference from [How to visualize groups of nodes in a d3 force-directed graph layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544041/how-to-visualize-groups-of-nodes-in-a-d3-force-directed-graph-layout)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
  .links line {
    stroke: #999;
    stroke-opacity: 0.6;
  }

  .nodes circle {
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

  path {
    opacity: 0.4;
    stroke-width: 0px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

  var voronoi = d3
    .voronoi()
    .x(function (d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .extent([
      [-1, -1],
      [width + 1, height + 1],
    ]);

  var simulation = d3
    .forceSimulation()
    .force(
      "link",
      d3
        .forceLink()
        .id(function (d) {
          return d.id;
        })
        .strength(function (link) {
          if (link.source.group == link.source.target) {
            return 1;
          } else {
            return 0.1;
          }
        })
    )
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-20))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  d3.json("data.json", function (error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

    var link = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter()
      .append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function (d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.value);
      });

    var node = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.group);
      })
      .call(
        d3
          .drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended)
      );

    node.append("title").text(function (d) {
      return d.id;
    });

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes).on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);

    // append voronoi
    var cells = svg
      .selectAll()
      .data(simulation.nodes())
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("fill", function (d) {
        return color(d.group);
      })
      .attr("class", function (d) {
        return d.group;
      });

    var cell = cells.append("path").data(voronoi.polygons(simulation.nodes()));

    function ticked() {
      var alpha = this.alpha();
      var nodes = this.nodes();

      var coords = {};
      var groups = [];

      // sort the nodes into groups:
      node.each(function (d) {
        if (groups.indexOf(d.group) == -1) {
          groups.push(d.group);
          coords[d.group] = [];
        }

        coords[d.group].push({ x: d.x, y: d.y });
      });

      // get the centroid of each group:
      var centroids = {};

      for (var group in coords) {
        var groupNodes = coords[group];

        var n = groupNodes.length;
        var cx = 0;
        var tx = 0;
        var cy = 0;
        var ty = 0;

        groupNodes.forEach(function (d) {
          tx += d.x;
          ty += d.y;
        });

        cx = tx / n;
        cy = ty / n;

        centroids[group] = { x: cx, y: cy };
      }

      // don't modify points close the the group centroid:
      var minDistance = 10;

      if (alpha < 0.1) {
        minDistance = 10 + 1000 * (0.1 - alpha);
      }

      // adjust each point if needed towards group centroid:
      node.each(function (d) {
        var cx = centroids[d.group].x;
        var cy = centroids[d.group].y;
        var x = d.x;
        var y = d.y;
        var dx = cx - x;
        var dy = cy - y;

        var r = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

        if (r > minDistance) {
          d.x = x * 0.9 + cx * 0.1;
          d.y = y * 0.9 + cy * 0.1;
        }
      });

      // update voronoi:
      cell = cell
        .data(voronoi.polygons(simulation.nodes()))
        .attr("d", renderCell);

      // update links:
      link
        .attr("x1", function (d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function (d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function (d) {
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function (d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });

      // update nodes:
      node
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
          return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
          return d.y;
        });
    }
  });

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

  function renderCell(d) {
    return d == null ? null : "M" + d.join("L") + "Z";
  }
</script>




    {
  "nodes": [
    { "id": "Myriel", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "Napoleon", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "Geborand", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "Champtercier", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "Cravatte", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "Count", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "OldMan", "group": 1 },
    { "id": "Labarre", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Valjean", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Marguerite", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "Mme.deR", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Isabeau", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Gervais", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Tholomyes", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "Listolier", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "Fameuil", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "Blacheville", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "Favourite", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "Dahlia", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "Zephine", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "Fantine", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Thenardier", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Cosette", "group": 5 },
    { "id": "Javert", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0 },
    { "id": "Bamatabois", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Perpetue", "group": 3 },
    { "id": "Simplice", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Woman1", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Judge", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Champmathieu", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Brevet", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Chenildieu", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Cochepaille", "group": 2 },
    { "id": "Pontmercy", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Boulatruelle", "group": 6 },
    { "id": "Eponine", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Anzelma", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Woman2", "group": 5 },
    { "id": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0 },
    { "id": "Gribier", "group": 0 },
    { "id": "Jondrette", "group": 7 },
    { "id": "Mme.Burgon", "group": 7 },
    { "id": "Gavroche", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "Gillenormand", "group": 5 },
    { "id": "Magnon", "group": 5 },
    { "id": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5 },
    { "id": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5 },
    { "id": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5 },
    { "id": "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5 },
    { "id": "Marius", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "BaronessT", "group": 5 },
    { "id": "Mabeuf", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "Enjolras", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "Combeferre", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "Prouvaire", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "Feuilly", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "Courfeyrac", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "Bahorel", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "Bossuet", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "Joly", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "Grantaire", "group": 8 },
    { "id": "MotherPlutarch", "group": 9 },
    { "id": "Gueulemer", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Babet", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Claquesous", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Montparnasse", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Toussaint", "group": 5 },
    { "id": "Child1", "group": 10 },
    { "id": "Child2", "group": 10 },
    { "id": "Brujon", "group": 4 },
    { "id": "Mme.Hucheloup", "group": 8 }
  ],
  "links": [
    { "source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8 },
    { "source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10 },
    { "source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 6 },
    { "source": "CountessdeLo", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Geborand", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Champtercier", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Cravatte", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Count", "target": "Myriel", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "OldMan", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Valjean", "target": "Labarre", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Valjean", "target": "Mme.Magloire", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Valjean", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Valjean", "target": "Myriel", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Marguerite", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mme.deR", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Isabeau", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Gervais", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Listolier", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Fameuil", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Fameuil", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Blacheville", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Blacheville", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Blacheville", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Favourite", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Favourite", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Favourite", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Favourite", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Dahlia", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Dahlia", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Dahlia", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Dahlia", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Dahlia", "target": "Favourite", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Zephine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Zephine", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Marguerite", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Fantine", "target": "Valjean", "value": 9 },
    { "source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 7 },
    { "source": "Thenardier", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 13 },
    { "source": "Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 12 },
    { "source": "Cosette", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Cosette", "target": "Valjean", "value": 31 },
    { "source": "Cosette", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Cosette", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Javert", "target": "Valjean", "value": 17 },
    { "source": "Javert", "target": "Fantine", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Javert", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Javert", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Javert", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 8 },
    { "source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Perpetue", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Simplice", "target": "Perpetue", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Simplice", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Simplice", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Simplice", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Scaufflaire", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Woman1", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Woman1", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Judge", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Judge", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Brevet", "target": "Judge", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Brevet", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Brevet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Brevet", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Judge", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Chenildieu", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Pontmercy", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Boulatruelle", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Eponine", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Eponine", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Anzelma", "target": "Eponine", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Anzelma", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Anzelma", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Woman2", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Woman2", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Woman2", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Gribier", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Mme.Burgon", "target": "Jondrette", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Gavroche", "target": "Mme.Burgon", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Gavroche", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Gavroche", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Gavroche", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Magnon", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Magnon", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 9 },
    { "source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mlle.Vaubois", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Marius", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 6 },
    { "source": "Marius", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 12 },
    { "source": "Marius", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Marius", "target": "Lt.Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Marius", "target": "Cosette", "value": 21 },
    { "source": "Marius", "target": "Valjean", "value": 19 },
    { "source": "Marius", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Marius", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Marius", "target": "Eponine", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Marius", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "BaronessT", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "BaronessT", "target": "Marius", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Marius", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Enjolras", "target": "Marius", "value": 7 },
    { "source": "Enjolras", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7 },
    { "source": "Enjolras", "target": "Javert", "value": 6 },
    { "source": "Enjolras", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Enjolras", "target": "Valjean", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Combeferre", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 15 },
    { "source": "Combeferre", "target": "Marius", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Combeferre", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 6 },
    { "source": "Combeferre", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 6 },
    { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Feuilly", "target": "Marius", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Marius", "value": 9 },
    { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 17 },
    { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 13 },
    { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7 },
    { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6 },
    { "source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 6 },
    { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Bahorel", "target": "Marius", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Marius", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 12 },
    { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 10 },
    { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6 },
    { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 9 },
    { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Bossuet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Joly", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Joly", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 7 },
    { "source": "Joly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Joly", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Joly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Joly", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Joly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Joly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Joly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Joly", "target": "Marius", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Joly", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Grantaire", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "MotherPlutarch", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5 },
    { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Babet", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 6 },
    { "source": "Babet", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 6 },
    { "source": "Babet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Babet", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Babet", "target": "Javert", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Babet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Babet", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Babet", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 4 },
    { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Claquesous", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Babet", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Toussaint", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Toussaint", "target": "Javert", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Toussaint", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Child1", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Child2", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2 },
    { "source": "Child2", "target": "Child1", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Babet", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3 },
    { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Brujon", "target": "Montparnasse", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Joly", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Grantaire", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1 },
    { "source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: D3 removed d3.schemeCategory20 in v5, voronoi had a number of changes as the voronoi module was swapped for a new one with a different name (d3.deluany) if memory serves.